# Refactoring *ngIf Container

Tags: angular

I am looking for a better way of refactoring the following code that I have:

```
<div class="container">
    <icon class="icon" *ngIf="A || B"></icon>
    <div class="itemOne" *ngIf="A"></div>
    <div class="itemTwo" *ngIf="B"></div>
</div>
```

I feel like there is too much-duplicated code in this, but it might also be one of those situations where readability is preferred over any clever tricks.

I looked into using `ng-template` and `[ngSwitch]` but couldn't come up with a final solution. `[ngSwitch]` seems like it could be a good candidate although I would have to make the test variable generic as `A` and `B` are of different types.

Thanks

Comment: Are `A` and `B` independent from each other? Can they evaluate to the same boolean value?

Comment: They cannot have the same value.

Comment: Then the icon is always displayed (because `A || B` is always `true`). For the two divs, you can use `ngIf ... else`.

Comment: The tricky part is yes, the icon will always show, but the container will _not_ always show. The container should only show up when a form validator fails, in which case an icon (always shown) alongside a message (conditionally shown) will appear. The container will show if either error cases are true, but the corresponding message will change depending on which case is true.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of if-else template by Angular which i believe will be readable and testable with ease.

```
<div *ngIf="A;else other_content">
    content here ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only difference between itemOne and itemTwo is a class, you could use conditionals in [ngClass] to get rid of one line and the *ngIf's:

```
<div class="container">
    <icon class="icon" *ngIf="A || B"></icon>    
    <div [ngClass]="{ 'itemOne': A, 'itemTwo' B }"></div>
</div>
```

However, this also means that the div will always be displayed, even if both A and B are false. You can take care of this by moving '*ngIf="A || B"' from icon to the container div - that of course depends on the use-case.

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="A || B">
    <icon class="icon"></icon>    
    <div [ngClass]="{ 'itemOne': A, 'itemTwo' B }"></div>
</div>
```